# Weird behavior of SKAction on children

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit, game-development, skaction

Well, my aim is to extract the content of a `SKScene` and then run some actions to their node:

```
func loadSceneNodes() {
    let loadedScene = SKScene(fileNamed: "newScene.sks")

    // Reads the content of the "Content" node in the newScene.sks
    let content = loadedScene!.childNode(withName: "Content") as! SKSpritenode

    // I move the content to self
    // (THANKS Knight0fDragon for suggestion)
    content.move(toParent: self)

    // Forces the unpause
    self.isPause = false

    // Try to run a test action on the node
    content.run(.rotate(byAngle: 90, duration: 2.0)) {
        print("DONE")
    }

    print(content.hasActions()) // DEBUG -> it prints TRUE
}
```

What happens is that I successful read the content and it shows on the scene, but the actions aren't shown even if `hasActions()` results `true`.

I found out something very interesting by playing with breakpoints and the debug console. `content.hasActions()` returns `true` because all of the `SKActions` get into a stack:

[image]

They seem like freeze because if I assign more actions, they will get stack in the pile one by one without getting run.
Only **once I quit** the breakpoint (or whether I pause and then play the application through xCode) everything is executed. Just like the app "needs" a refresh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `moveToParent` on your sknode instead of `addChild` on your parent node to avoid the need to create a copy.

Ensure the `isPaused` state is set to false, you may be copying at a time where it is true

Comment: Thanks for replying. I adopted the ```move(toParent:)``` func instead of ```copy()``` and it works fine. The problem is that the ```SKActions``` still doesn't work. :(

Comment: Did you check the isPaused? Also, the scene needs to be attached to a view prior to doing this.

Comment: ```isPaused``` is set to false by default. What do you mean by "needs to be attached"?

Comment: Just because it is set to fault be default does not mean it wont get changed.  Sprite kit changes it back and forth during the loading process of a scene.  All SKScenes need to be attached to an SKView.  You need to add your actions after it is assigned to a view so that your timing is properly synced up.

Comment: SOLVED! You were right, @Knight0fDragon, I should have "unpause" the ```content```. I misunderstood you and I used to unpause the scene itself, my fault. Thanks for helping me